# Curl GET from vagrant nodejs. The requested URL could not be retrieved from requested server

Tags: node.js, curl, vagrant

Trying to run the following curl command from nodeJS vagrant virtual box.

IP address for localhost - 10.29.12.152

curl http://10.29.12.152:3002/api/v1/suggest/zeta-spot-cms/documents?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9CJyfw&term=xfinity

And also, I have developed the list API endpoint using expressJS.

If I run the above mentioned API endpoint in web browser, it will get the results from local environment.

```
[
{
_index: "zeta-spot-cms",
_type: "documents",
_id: "AVmCw40nHO6bFVnpAj-5",
_score: 1,
_source: {}
}
]
```

Trying to use this API as curl command in vagrant virtual box. I got following error.

```
<div id="titles">
<h1>ERROR</h1>
<h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="content">
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="http://10.29.12.152:3002/api/v1/suggest/zeta-spot-cms/documents?">http://10.29.12.152:3002/api/v1/suggest/zeta-spot-cms/documents?</a></p>

<blockquote id="error">
<p><b>Connection to 10.29.12.152 failed.</b></p>
</blockquote>

<p id="sysmsg">The system returned: <i>(113) No route to host</i></p>

<p>The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.</p>
```

Can you please suggest me, How can I raise the curl command in vagrant virtual box to get the localhost's results.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard for me to understand exactly what you're asking, so let me first clarify -- I interpret your question to mean that you have a virtualbox VM that Vagrant is managing, and you have a node.js application running inside that VM. When you access the application through your (host system's) browser, you get the results you are expecting. But when you try to use `curl` from inside the VM, you get the "no route to host" error copied above.

Assuming this is all correct, I think the answer is pretty simple. I'm guessing that virtualbox VM does not know that its IP address is 10.29.12.152. Consequently, commands run from inside the VM do not know how to reach that IP address. From your description, it's not clear to me whether that IP is coming from, either.

If my hypothesis is correct, you should be able to replace 10.29.12.152 with 127.0.0.1 and the command should work.

A further troubleshooting technique would be to run `ifconfig` on the command line, and see what IP addresses show up.

Comment: thanks for quick response @Geoff Gerrietts, Nodejs application is not running in virtualbox VM. Which is running in local machine(10.29.12.152). I want to run the curl command in inside the virtualbox VM. If I give 127.0.0.1 instead of IP address, I got curl: (7) couldn't connect to host error.

Comment: Actually, I want call this API in another application, which is running in virtualbox VM

Comment: And also I have checked with ping command in VM. Results are as follows:

PING 10.29.12.152 (10.219.162.152) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.29.12.152: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.361 ms
64 bytes from 10.29.12.152: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.296 ms

Comment: Node app may not be binding to the address?